# Cross Referencing Across Folders and Files

Tags: cross-referencing

I'm trying to cross reference a chapter number in my thesis. I have each chapter in a separate folder using overleaf), but I cannot figure out how to cross reference. For example, I have the following file structure:

folder called body with contemporarynetworks.tex inside, and a folder called introduction with introduction.tex inside.

The Introduction chapter looks like:

```
\chapter{Introduction}
These areas are explored in greater detail in chapter \autoref{connetworks}
```

And the contemporarynetworks chapter looks like:

```
\chapter{Contemporary Intra-Vehicular Networks and Standards}
\label{connetworks}
Description of networks.
```

However, regardless of what I try, I cannot get the Introduction to properly cross reference. I've tried using \hyperref, and when I try using \autoref in the introduction, overleaf autocomplete 'finds' the connetworks label, but it doesn't compile. I have also tried adding the folder it is found in, like:

```
\autoref{body/connetworks}
```

and the file like

```
\autoref{body/contemporarynetworks/connetworks}
```

But again it only shows ?? when compiled. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Under normal circumstances `\autoref{connetworks}` should be enough. If not, please explain in more detail how your document is setup, and preferably provide full example code that show your issues.

Comment: assuming that all chapters are part of the same document just included with `\input` or `\include` then you just need `\ref{connetworks}` the file structure  does not affect the cross referencing. But you have shown no relevant source code so it is hard to be sure.